# JNI - c++ variable value to Java-application

Tags: java, android, c++, java-native-interface

So I have this JNI function which gives me some x and y values.
I want to send the values to the java Application, but since its a JNICall i am lost of how to do this?

```
JNIEXPORT void JNICALL Java_com_example_foo(JNIEnv env*, jclass FooClass, jlong matRgba,) {
    Mat& rgba = *(Mat*)matRgba;
  jmethodID mid_getCoord = env->GetStaticMethodID(FooClass, "getCoord", "(II)V");

    detect(rgba);
}

void detect(Mat& frame){
  String eye_cascade_name = "test.eyes.cascade.xml";

CascadeClassifier eyes_cascade;
std::vector<Rect> eyes;
Mat frame_gray;


for (size_t i = 0; i < eyes.size(); i++){
    Point center(eyes[i].x + eyes[i].width*0.5, eyes[i].y + eyes[i].height*0.5);

  env->CallStaticVoidMethod(FooClass, mid_getCoord, eyes[i].x, eyes[i].y);


    ellipse(frame, center, Size(eyes[i].width*0.5, eyes[i].height*0.5));

    Mat eyesROI = frame_gray(eyes[i]);
}
```

}

TO DO; Send these two values (x and y) to the Java application? 
*Notice that these values constantly change value.

What I have thought of so far. Is that creating x and y as global values and set them to eyes[i].x and y and somehow send them to the application.. I'm not sure if this is the correct way to do it, and I've tried with different attempts but with failure.. Got multiple NDK errors which Isn't really telling me of what is wrong.. So Im bascially stuck of how to solve this issue..

Any help is appreciated!

Java class;

```
public class FooClass {
public native static void eyeDetection(long matRgba);
static void getCoord(int x, int y) {
    System.out.println("got coordinates: " + x + ", " + y);
}
```

Im probably doing something wrong here but how do I return these values to the java application

The detect method is working perfectly fine.. Its some opencv stuff, and it draws an ellipse at the eyes as it should.. I just need to pass the coordinates of eyes[i].x and eyes[i].y

Comment: Your code is incomplete, how are you able to dereference vector `cubes` in for loop if it's empty (you just created it)?

Comment: Yes I didn't provide the whole colde, thought that as long as the idea is there it would be sufficient

Comment: Ok also what do you mean by `Notice that these values constantly change value.` Do you want to return every `x` and `y` produced in a for loop?

Comment: It's unclear what you mean by _"the application"_. Which specific class are you talking about? Is it the same class that calls `foo`? Do you want to call some method in that class or were you planning on writing directly to its fields? Does `foo` need to be static or could it be an instance method?

Comment: pbn: Yes the loop constantly changes values and it needs to be sent to the application(java) instantly...


Micheal: Yes lets say for instance 
        public native static void foo(int x, int y);

And the method is being used to show some x and y values in the java class

Comment: But if it's static, which instance's values are supposed to be modified?

Comment: cube[i].x and cube[i].y is being constantly changed.. 
Its a static function just so that I can access it in my java class
The detect() method changes the values for cube[i].x cube[i].y all the time I just need to return it continously to the application

Comment: You still haven't clarified _which specific_ object you want to pass the values to.

Comment: Thats the part im not sure how to do..

So how do I save the values of cube[i].x and cube[i].y (which is a integer) as a global reference and send it to the java application.. Thats the part I just can't figure how to do so.
I tried to set jint x = cube[i].x and jint y = cube[i].y but it gives compilation error with ndk...

Comment: `int`s are primitives. There are no references involved. Ans as always: if you've got error messages you need to put them _in your question_.

Comment: Ok not sure If this is what you mean by reference.. So I updated the post with int references.. please take a look again..

Comment: Why are `x` and `y` declared in `foo` when it's `detect` that uses them?

Comment: @Michael Please try to take a look now. I've updated the question with more detailed code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get the results back from your native code, you can define a callback method in your Java.

```
package com.example.foo;
public class Foo {
    public native static void eyeDetection(long addrRgba);
    static void getCoord(int x, int y) {
      System.out.println("got coordinates: " + x + ", " + y);
      // consume the coordinates in Java, e.g.
      Foo2.onCreate(x, y);
    }
}
```

```
JNIEXPORT void JNICALL Java_com_example_foo_Foo_eyeDetection(JNIEnv *env, jclass FooClass, jlong matRgba) {
  Mat& rgba = *(Mat*)matRgba;
  jmethodID mid_getCoord = env->GetStaticMethodID(FooClass, "getCoord", "(II)V");
   String eye_cascade_name = "test.eyes.cascade.xml";

  CascadeClassifier eyes_cascade;
  std::vector<Rect> eyes;
  eyes_cascade.detectMultiScale(…);
  for (size_t i = 0; i < eyes.size(); i++) {
    env->CallStaticVoidMethod(FooClass, mid_getCoord, eyes[i].x, eyes[i].y);
    …
  }
}
```

Note that if you want to perform the callback not on the thread that was used to invoke **eyeDetection()**, you must attach that thread to JVM (obtaining a distinct thread-dependent JNIEnv pointer), and keep a global reference to the **FooClass**.

Comment: Wow.. I will try this out!
- It has to be in the same thread as eyeDetection() since this is the one who expose the coordinates.

Comment: shouldn't     static void getCoord(int x, int y);
 be         public native static void getCoord(int x, int y);

?

Comment: No, it's a Java method that *consumes* `x, y` to do drawing or whatever. That's why I believe you may find it must use a separate thread after all.

Comment: Won't the data be out of sync then? I mean lets say that in the detect() eyes[i].x, eyes[i].y = (30,60) and in a nano second it changes to (40,80) and I might miss some data in thread 2 (getCoords) since the threads are async and won't know when to do the callback?

Comment: There is no doubt your callback will always be a bit too late for the input coming from the camera, but depending on your task, you may not need a separate thread for callbacks after all.

Comment: I see. yes In my case it might not really matter, since the x, y cooridnates are used to place a textview in the java-application. But with some delays I believe its fine. - Might be a stupid question. But how do I see if I recieve the coordinates from static void getCoord(int x, int y) { // consume the coordinates in Java }?? I called the method from another class; 
class Foo2 {
Foo.getCoord(int x, int y) {
// How should I get the x and y coordinates? lets say I just want to System.out.print to see if I recieve them or not?
}
}
Since the method required some parameters??
- Thanks!

Comment: But the issue here is I need to call this method inside of another class? and when I do so I need to pass some x and y parameters?
Lets say for instance in Foo2 I have method called updateTextView(int x, int y) {
// and here the data from getCoord (JNI) should be fetched and set to the updateTextView method
}

Comment: Another thing as well, When I build the application it says that; use of undeclared identifier 'env' same with foo and mid_getCoord
I did the same as you posted in your answer.
Do I need to include something or?
Thanks for the great help appreciate it a lot!

Comment: env is the first argument if the JNI implementation of your native eyeDetection method. You may post your updated code for inspection.

Comment: There you go,  I've updated the code.I get the following error when building;
Error:error: use of undeclared identifier 'env'
Error:error: use of undeclared identifier 'FooClass'
Error:error: use of undeclared identifier 'mid_getCoord'
Error:Execution failed for task ':app:ndkBuild'.
> Process 'command 'C:/Users/Theone/AppData/Local/Android/Sdk/ndk-bundle/ndk-build.cmd'' finished with non-zero exit value 2

Comment: Naturally variables must be declared in (or passed to) the same scope (or its surrounding scope) where they will be used. `detect` has no knowledge of anything declared in `Java_com_example_foo`.

Comment: Im not that familiar with JNI and c++. So how do I declare variables so they are inside of the scope? like global variable or anything like this?

Comment: To make the things easy, delete the lines from detect to detect, don't have a separate function.

Comment: I see deleting the void detect and detect(rgba) and set     Mat& frame= *(Mat*)matRgba; right?

so all the logic is inside one JNI Call method?

Comment: Okay I got it to work :D! thanks a lot!
Just one more question..
So when I call Foo.getCoord(int x, int y) In another class lets say Foo2.
How do I pass the values with it? I tried to System.out.print it.. But it didn't seems to work.
In Foo2  {  int x, y    Oncreate{       Foo.getCoord(x, y); 
system.out.print("x: ", x + "y: " + y)
}

If you get what I mean

Comment: @AlexCohn 
Should I change the static void getCoord(int x, int y) { to return an int[x,y] instead? Since As I see it, is that the Foo class is like the interface of the JNI call since its based upon this class I create the cpp and h files. For the eyeDetection() it uses native so when I call it and retrieves the data in class Foo2 { I do; Foo.eyeDetection(mRgba.getNativeObjAddr()); } which return the rgba from the JNI function. But with the getCoord its a bit different, so how do I approach this?
Since I have an Update method in Foo2 I need to pass the values. the print works in the Foo clas

Comment: When I call the static method in Foo2 I dont get the values.

Comment: You could call any static method of any class directly from the native code. If you have a reference to a Java object, you can call its non-static methods, too. To keep this as simple as possible, though, do it in Foo class.

Comment: I see! You are the real MVP! Thanks for clarification and answer!

Comment: @JamesTrix There are common designs when more complexity is appropriate. The "push model" of the GoF [Subscriber pattern](https://www.oodesign.com/observer-pattern.html) might suit you, but also consider the "pull model".

Comment: @AlexCohn you seem to have alot of knowledge about OpenCv and Android as well..

I've create a new question for this as well.. But I am having a real low FPS for some reason 2-3 fps! And I have no clue of how to improve this and if this is even possible is this something you can enlight me about?